# Application free memory

Tags: ios, memory

I want to develop an application where i want to free memory from other process that are currently running in my iOS device.

For me it is not possible as if iOS sandbox environment taken into consideration also it should not be a jailbreak device.I also know about memory management principle of cocoa touch.

But there are some application present in app store which claim to do this task.So is it possible to do so?

Comment: Which applications claim to do this? Nothing gets by Apple.

Comment: This is wacky. I think I read you to say that you want it to work on non-jailbroken devices. If so, the only way to "reclaim" memory from other running apps is to cause them to get killed by the OS by inflating your own memory usage and hoping that they'll be jettisoned instead of you.

Comment: The name of application : Memory Doctor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apps on the Store that claim to “free memory” probably do so by consuming increasing amounts of memory themselves until the system starts killing off background processes. They all work the same way, because of the sandbox—why bother duplicating that?

Comment: So are these kind claims to cheat the basic user & increase revenue.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the solution is to progressively consume memory until the system raise the memory warning level 1 and 2 then free that memory.  This way the system will try to claim every memory block it can from any running application.

Comment: I recommend loading something small a bunch of times to do that.  I accidentally did that once, springboard did a good job freeing it before I use it all up